# If $a+b+c = 4, a^2+b^2+c^2=7, a^3+b^3+c^3=28$ find $a^4+b^4+c^4$ and $a^5+b^5+c^5$

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-functions

I have tried to solve it but cannot find any approach which would lead me to the answer

Comment: Hint: Calculate $ab+bc+ca$ and $abc$ first. Then $(a+b+c)^4=?$ etc...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use [Newton’s identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to find $a,b,c$ as roots of a degree 3 polynomial.

Comment: Can this be solved *without* finding $a,b,c$?

Comment: Yes. Look precisely at Wikipedia article on [Newton’s identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities). You’re given $p_1,p_2, p_3$. From that you get $e_1,e_2,e_3$. And knowing that $e_i=0$ for $i>3$ you get $p_4,p_5$ which you’re requested to find.

Comment: Exactly! I suggest you add your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$$

and $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3bc=(a+b+c)\{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\}$$  to find $ab+bc+ca=u, abc=v$(say)

So, $a,b,c$ are the roots of $$t^3-4t^2+ut-v=0$$

Use [Newton's Sums](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Newton%27s_Sums)

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maple:

simplify(a^4+b^4+c^4, {a+b+c = 4, a^2+b^2+c^2 = 7, a^3+b^3+c^3 = 28}) = 209/2

simplify(a^5+b^5+c^5, {a+b+c = 4, a^2+b^2+c^2 = 7, a^3+b^3+c^3 = 28}) = 334

Answer (score 0):

$$a+b+c=4\,\Rightarrow\,(a+b+c)^2=16$$
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ac)=16\Rightarrow2(ab+bc+ac)=9$$
Now:
$$(a+b+c)^3=(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3\left[(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-abc\right]$$
$$64=28+3\left[4\times9-abc\right]\therefore\,abc=24$$
Now you need to try and simplify:
$${256=(a^4+b^4+c^4)+6(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)+4(ab^3+ac^3+ba^3+bc^3+ca^3+cb^3)+12(abc^2+acb^2+bca^2)}$$
By using other methods like the fact that:
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=(a^4+b^4+c^4)+2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2)$$