# What is $\alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

If 
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 14  $$
$$ \alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2} = 84 $$
$$ \alpha^{3} + \beta^{3} + \gamma^{3} = 584 $$

What is $\alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4}$?

---

**Attempt:**

Notice that
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 14 \implies \alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2}  + 2(\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \alpha \gamma) = 196$$
$$\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2}  + 2(\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \alpha \gamma) = 196 \implies 84 + 2(\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \alpha \gamma) = 196  $$
$$ \alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \alpha \gamma = 56 $$

Also
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 14 \implies \alpha^{3} + \beta^{3} + \gamma^{3}  + 3(\alpha^{2} \beta + \alpha^{2} \gamma + \beta^{2} \alpha + \beta^{2} \gamma + \gamma^{2} \alpha + \gamma^{2} \beta) + 3 \alpha \beta \gamma = 2744$$
$$ 584 = 2744 - 3(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)(\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma) + 6 \alpha \beta \gamma$$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma = 32$$

So that

$$ (\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^{4} = ( \alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2}  + 2(\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \alpha \gamma) )^{2} $$
$$ 38416 = (\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2})^{2} + 4 (\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma)(\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2} + \gamma^{2}) + 4 (\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma)^{2}$$
$$ 38416 = \left[ \alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} + 2 \left( (\alpha \beta)^{2} + (\beta \gamma)^{2} + (\alpha \gamma)^{2} \right) \right] + 4 (56)(84) + 4 (56^{2}) $$
$$ 7056 = \alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} + 2 \left( (\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma)^{2} - 2\alpha \beta \gamma(\alpha + \beta + \gamma ) \right) $$
$$ 7056= \alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} + 2 \left( 56^{2} - 2(32)(14) \right) $$
$$\alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} = 2576$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325068/if-abc-4-a2b2c2-7-a3b3c3-28-find-a4b4c4-and-a5b5c/3325072#3325072

Comment: So what is the question?  It appears you have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define $A,B,C$ such that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma) = x^3 - Ax^2 + Bx - C$.

For any $n \ge 1$, let $p_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + \gamma^n$. In terms of $p_n$, the question becomes:

> Given $p_1 = 14, p_2 = 84, p_3 = 584$, what is $p_4$?

There is a bunch of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) connecting $p_n$ and the coefficients $A,B,C$ above.
Using these identities, the computation of $p_4 = \alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4$ is mechanical.

- $p_1 = A \\ \quad \implies A = 14$
- $p_2 = A p_1 - 2B  \\ \quad  \implies  B = \frac12(A^2 - p_2) = \frac12(14^2 - 84) = 56$
- $p_3 = A p_2 - B p_1 + 3C \\ \quad \implies C = \frac13 ( p_3 - Ap_2 + B p_1)
  = \frac13(584 - 14\cdot 84 + 56\cdot 14) = 64$

Finally, we have

$$p^4 = Ap_3 - Bp_2 + Cp_1 = 14\cdot 584 - 56\cdot 84 + 64\cdot 14 = 4368$$

This is different from what you have got. 
When you compute $\alpha\beta\gamma$, you have make a mistake in one of the coefficient. The correct step should be

$$584 = 2744 - 3(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)(\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma) + \color{red}{3} \alpha \beta \gamma\\
\implies \alpha\beta\gamma = \color{red}{64}
$$

Other than this, the rest of your derivation seems fine. In fact, if you substitute $32$ by $64$ in last two lines, you get the right answer.
$$\require{cancel}
 7056= \alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} + 2 \left( 56^{2} - 2(\color{red}{\cancelto{64}{\color{gray}{32}}})(14) \right) $$
$$\alpha^{4} + \beta^{4} + \gamma^{4} = 
\color{red}{\cancelto{4368}{\color{gray}{2576}}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$, $y=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2$ and $z=\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3$ for any real numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Then we have the identity:
$$\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4=\frac16\left(x^4-6x^2y+3y^2+8xz\right).\tag{1}$$
You can verify this by expanding everything. In our case, $x=14,y=84$ and $z=584$, so just substitute in the numbers to solve the problem. I get the answer of $4368$.

(Note: I came up with the expression $(1)$ with a computer running *Mathematica.* It might not be very viable in a competition setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, its visible clearly that numbers are 8, 4 and 2.
From first two equations, $$y = 1/2 (-\sqrt{-3 x^2 + 28 x - 28} - x + 14)$$
 $$z = 1/2 (\sqrt
{-3x^2 + 28 x - 28} - x + 14)$$
Putting them into third equation, we get  a cubic equation
$$3x^3 - 42 x^2 + 168 x + 392=584$$  solving which by cardano or any method or writing the symmetric equation for sum and product of  roots etc, we see that roots are 2, 4 and 8. 
[image]

Comment: You should enclose the contents of a square root with curly brackets { } instead of parentheses ( ). That will make them come out correct. Compare: $\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.